# How to make this condition more Scala-like

Tags: java, scala, idioms

I have the following method:

```
def generateAssociatedImages : List[ImageFileEntry] = {

    if ( this.page > 1 && this.page < this.fileEntry.pageCount ) {
        List( copyWithPage( this.page - 1 ), copyWithPage( this.page + 1 ) )
    } else {
        if ( page == 1 && page != file.fileEntry.pageCount ) {
            List( copyWithPage( this.page + 1 ) )
        } else {
            List( copyWithPage( this.page - 1 ) )
        }
    }

}
```

But this one looks too much like Java (if I was using Ruby I'd do a switch/case on a range and then do the other comparisons). Is there a more funcional way to do this in Scala?

The behavior is quite simple:

- if input is page 1 and total pages is 3, the output is [2]
- if input is page 2 and total pages is 3, the output is [1,3]
- if input is page 3 and total pages is 3, the output is [2]

I'm looking for an idiomatic solution, I'm still new to Scala.

It would be lovely if I could do something like:

```
( 1 until 3 ).hasNext( 2 )
```

Comment: What if there is only one page? In your snippet it seems to answers [0] (according to your notation) Is it valid?

Comment: There's another method before this one that will not try to generate images if there is only one page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that on a one page, the list of images is empty, you can have the following:

```
def generateAssociatedImages: List[ImageFileEntry] = {
    val pageCount = fileEntry.pageCount
    page match {
        case `pageCount` if page == 1 => List()
        case `pageCount` => List(copyWithPage(pageCount - 1))
        case 1 => List(copyWithPage(2))
        case x => List(copyWithPage(x - 1), copyWithPage(x + 1))
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great, just what I was looking for. Question, why the smart quotes in there?

Comment: Otherwise the `pageCount` will be considered as a new variable in the scope of the `match` block (and you will never go further than the second case).

Comment: You could achieve the same thing by capitalizing `PageCount`.

Comment: Yes, but i prefer to keep capitals for objects. It depends of your code guidelines or of your preferences.

Answer (score 2):

```
def ifTrue[T](c : Boolean, v : =>T) = if (c) Some(v) else None

def generateAssociatedImages = List(ifTrue(this.page > 1, -1)), ifTrue(this.page < this.fileEntry.pageCount, 1)).flatten.map(d => copyWithPage(this.page + d))
```

Comment: Even if it produces the good result, it looks quite unreadable, no?

Comment: Yep, and it becomes even more unreadable here, but it's nice to see that so we can avoid clever code.

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the beholder. My code eliminates repetition, your code for example has four calls to copyWithPage and two copies of identical page index logic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the adjacent pages?

```
val pages = 1 to this.fileEntry.pageCount

implicit def toNext(r: Range) = new { 
    def next(n: Int) = r.view sliding 2 find (n == _.head) map (_.last)
}

def adjacent(page: Int) = List(pages next page, pages.reverse next page).flatten

def generateAssociatedImages : List[ImageFileEntry] = 
    adjacent(this.page) map copyWithPage
```

It's a bit of an over-engineering, I admit. But it is elegant. It doesn't work for single-paged ranges either, because of a bug in `sliding`.